# Installing Ubuntu on Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, memory

I know that there are similiar questions to these, but I searched them and tried but I didn't succeed. Basically, I have downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version from Ubunto site, however when I am installing it in my Virtual Box, it gets completed to some part, and then it doesn't load.
I have attached the screenshot for clarity. [It isn't proceeding after this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8iD6.jpg)

On a side note- I have Mac OS, and have dedicated 2CPU for this UBUNTU with maximum possible 4.
I have allocated 2048 MB RAM to it with the maximum possible 4096MB.

My current total free memory in mac is around 2GB
I have allocated 25GB to this Ubuntu

Comment: 1. *I have downloaded Ubuntu 22.10 from Ubunto desktop site*... This is wrong. It's **Ubuntu** and the 22.10 (October 2022) isn't available now (by the usual download links) and about to become EoL (End of Life) so, for starters, DON`T use it. The current normal release is **23.04** and the Long Term Support one (preferable) is still **22.04**. 2. When running VMs never assign more than half of the resources, it's the golden rule. Check your settings before anything else.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Actually i meant i installed using this, the LTS  one  22.04 only sorry, https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop . Also, what exactly should I check in my settings?

Comment: So, again, the LTS is 22.04, not 22.10 which was an interim release supported for 9 months only. About the settings I mean the Virtualbox settings. Make sure the CPUs are half or less and the same for RAM, that should be all.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, I have installed 22.04 LTS one.Also, I think those(RAM AND CPU) were already half or less, but the problem still persists as I had attached in the screenshot.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am not sure what do you mean by Ubuntu installer, but I think I followed the same steps as in the link provided by you, its just that at the end precisely after the "Who Are You?" page , there is a page which comes which I have attached in my screenshot. And it isn't loading after some point

Comment: Copying files isn't very fast when it's thousands of small files that need to be downloaded or downloaded AND decompressed, and running with 2 cores + 2GB RAM it would take a while to finish. How long did you actually wait for that part of the process?

Comment: @I31_aze More than 4 hours, but now its fixed , it was probably due to less memory